# Entity Framework Code First 3 way entity connection using data annotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm trying to define a connection between 3 entities using EF Code-First.

The best way to describe the connection is using this class diagram:

[image: Class Diagram]

The idea is to have a `Tab` with many `Shapes` & `Actions` in it.
Each `Shape` is defined by the `Actions` which created\modified it and associated to one one `Tab`.
Each action is being preformed in a specific `Tab` and is manipulating a `Shape` (create\ rename\ update\ delete).

I already managed to create this diagram in code, without the connection between the `Shape` and the `Tab`. This is where I'm stuck.

This is my code:

**Tab**

```
public class Tab
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<VAction> Actions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Shape> Shapes { get; set; }

}
```

**Action**

```
public class VAction
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Tab")]
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]        
    public int TabID { get; set; }       

    public string ShapeLbl { get; set; }

    public virtual Tab Tab { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ShapeLbl, TabID")]
    public virtual Shape Shape { get; set; }
}
```

**Shape**

```
public class Shape
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public string Lbl { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Tab")]
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int TabID { get; set; }

    public virtual Tab Tab { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<VAction> Actions { get; set; }


}
```

Currently I'm getting this error:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

Shape_VAction: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'TabID' on entity 'VAction' does not match the type of property 'Lbl' on entity 'Shape' in the referential constraint 'VAction_Shape'.
Shape_VAction: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'ShapeLbl' on entity 'VAction' does not match the type of property 'TabID' on entity 'Shape' in the referential constraint 'VAction_Shape'.
```

If you look at the error it tries to bind between the TabID and Lbl, I don't really understand why, cause I did define the order correctly. Can anyone elaborate on that part?

Help will be appreciated!

**UPDATE - SOLVED**

I have no idea how and why it matters, but since I saw the error is about the order. I just tried to replace it on both ends, and it surprisingly worked.

I changed from:

**Action:**

```
[ForeignKey("ShapeLbl, TabID")]
public virtual Shape Shape { get; set; }
```

**Shape:**

```
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
public string Lbl { get; set; }
[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
public int TabID { get; set; }
```

To:

**Action:**

```
[ForeignKey("TabID, ShapeLbl")]
public virtual Shape Shape { get; set; }
```

**Shape:**

```
[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
public string Lbl { get; set; }
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
public int TabID { get; set; }
```

I have no idea why this change works and the one before didn't. if someone knows why I would love to hear the answer cause I just spent a few good hours for nothing, at least I'd know why.

Comment: I removed a few unnecessary fields, I hope I copied everything correctly

Comment: Is the `[ForeignKey("Tab")]` wrong? Shouldn't it be [ForeignKey("TabId")] and listed as an attribute for `Tab`?

Comment: @Sam I think it works both ways. I tried that option as well, it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE - SOLVED**

I have no idea how and why it matters, but since I saw the error is about the order. I just tried to replace it on both ends, and it surprisingly worked.

I changed from:

**Action:**

```
[ForeignKey("ShapeLbl, TabID")]
public virtual Shape Shape { get; set; }
```

**Shape:**

```
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
public string Lbl { get; set; }
[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
public int TabID { get; set; }
```

To:

**Action:**

```
[ForeignKey("TabID, ShapeLbl")]
public virtual Shape Shape { get; set; }
```

**Shape:**

```
[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
public string Lbl { get; set; }
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
public int TabID { get; set; }
```

I have no idea why this change works and the one before didn't. if someone knows why I would love to hear the answer cause I just spent a few good hours for nothing, at least I'd know why.